# Add extra parameter in <script> tag using script_loader_tag

Tags: plugins, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I am using this code in my plugin to enqueue script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpfrank-ptbw-pinit-js', PTBW_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js/pinit.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

The `wp_enqueue_script` function making a default `<script>` tag output like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/development/wp-content/plugins/pin-it-button-pinterest-widgets/assets/js/pinit.js'></script>
```

Want to add some extra parameter into the script tags like:

```
<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" src="http://localhost/development/wp-content/plugins/pin-it-button-pinterest-widgets/assets/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

1. `asysnc`
2. `defer`
3. `data-pinhover="true"`

How do I achieve that using [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)?

Are there any hook or action to pass extra parameters?

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `script_loader_tag` filter to fulfill your requirement. add below code in your active theme's functions.php file. it will add extra parameter in your script tag.

```
function add_attribute_to_script_tag($tag, $handle) {
   # add script handles to the array below
   $scripts_to_defer = array('wpfrank-ptbw-pinit-js');

   foreach($scripts_to_defer as $defer_script) {
      if ($defer_script === $handle) {
         return str_replace(' src', '  async defer data-pin-hover="true" src', $tag);
      }
   }
   return $tag;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_attribute_to_script_tag', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Nice, but you could've also used `in_array( $defer_script, $scripts_to_defer )` as a shortcut for the `foreach ()`  :)

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes this would also work. Thanks for suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I revised the answer once more because I recently noticed how the [Twenty Twenty](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwenty/) developers use the `script_loader_tag` hook to add `async` and `defer` to the `<script>` tag for the theme scripts.

1. In `twentytwenty_theme_support()` in `functions.php`, [lines #139 & #140](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwenty/1.1/functions.php#L139):

   ```php
   $loader = new TwentyTwenty_Script_Loader();
   add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', array( $loader, 'filter_script_loader_tag' ), 10, 2 );
   ```
2. In `twentytwenty_register_scripts()` in `functions.php`, [lines #208 & #209](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwenty/1.1/functions.php#L208):

   ```php
   wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/index.js', array(), $theme_version, false );
   wp_script_add_data( 'twentytwenty-js', 'async', true );
   ```
3. And in the [`TwentyTwenty_Script_Loader` class](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwenty/1.1/classes/class-twentytwenty-script-loader.php):

   ```php
   public function filter_script_loader_tag( $tag, $handle ) {
       foreach ( [ 'async', 'defer' ] as $attr ) {
           if ( ! wp_scripts()->get_data( $handle, $attr ) ) {
               continue;
           }
           ...
       }
       return $tag;
   }
   ```

So what I'm trying to say/suggest, is that you should probably better off use the [`wp_script_add_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/) to add/register the custom HTML attributes (e.g. `async`) for your scripts and use the `wp_scripts()->get_data()` to check if the `<script>` tag should be added with the custom HTML attributes, without having to manually specify the handle (e.g. your `wpfrank-ptbw-pinit-js`).

And here's an example based on the above approach, where I'm registering a list of custom or extra HTML attributes for a script using `wp_script_add_data( '<handle>', 'html_attrs', [ list here ] )`. Additionally, I'm using PHP's [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for a more precise result, although `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` would also do.

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_scripts' );
function my_register_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpfrank-ptbw-pinit-js', PTBW_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/js/pinit.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_script_add_data( 'wpfrank-ptbw-pinit-js', 'html_attrs', [
        'async'          => 'async',
        'defer'          => true,
        'data-pin-hover' => 'true',
    ] );
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'my_filter_script_loader_tag', 10, 2 );
function my_filter_script_loader_tag( $tag, $handle ) {
    $attrs = wp_scripts()->get_data( $handle, 'html_attrs' );

    // Bail if the script doesn't have any registered custom HTML attrs.
    if ( empty( $attrs ) || ! is_array( $attrs ) ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    $dom = new DOMDocument;

    //$tag = mb_convert_encoding( $tag, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' );
    $dom->loadHTML( $tag, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

    $node = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'script' )[0];
    foreach ( $attrs as $key => $value ) {
        $node->setAttribute( $key, $value );
    }

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the new update. Appreciated!

Comment: I made one last update... I think instead of two identical answers to the question, why not post an alternate solution, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Chetan Vaghela answer, you can use a switch statement, only for performance and customization related purposes:

```
function add_attribute_to_script_tag($tag, $handle) {

    switch($handle){
        case 'wpfrank-ptbw-pinit-js': return str_replace(' src', ' async defer data-pin-hover="true" src', $tag);
        default: return $tag;
    }
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_attribute_to_script_tag', 10, 2);
```